# Seeking definition of discriminative loss function

Tags: machine-learning

Could someone explain what is meant by a discriminative loss function in the context of deep learning?

Comment: You may get better mileage on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Discriminative models (such as SVM) are able to optimize a boundary between classes. They do this by optimizing a loss function.

The loss function usually refers to the **objective function**, which tells the optimizer how much closer/farther each step is from an optimal solution.

Take stochastic gradient descent for example, which you can imagine as a blind hiker slowly seeking the lowest valley.

The hiker's loss function is essentially "what is my current elevation?"

Answer (score 0):

Look at this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02551
Here is describing this loss function for semantic image segmentation